# D3D11 CreateDeferredContext Error without ever creating a deferred render context

Tags: rendering, directx-11, deferred-rendering

I get the following error message in my output window :-

```
D3D11 ERROR: ID3D11Device::CreateDeferredContext: Creation of a Device with D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_SINGLETHREADED prevents the creation of deferred contexts. [ STATE_CREATION ERROR #2097162: CREATEDEFERREDCONTEXT_SINGLETHREADED]

D3D11 ERROR: ID3D11Device::CreateDeferredContext: CreateDeferredContext returning DXGI_ERROR_INVALID_CALL, meaning the function can not be used. [ STATE_CREATION ERROR #2097164: CREATEDEFERREDCONTEXT_INVALID_CALL_RETURN]
```

But I never call that function and also I have a single threaded immediate 
render context. This started happening abruptly.

Also, If i do a search for that function call then i get 0 hits in my entire solution.

Update 1 - The culprit seems to swap hain present because even if I don't create any shaders and buffers and just the context device and swapchain I still get this error

Update 2 - I have already tried the following -

1. Re-build the solution in debug and release mode.
2. Attaching the debugger by directly running the program on different graphic cards.
3. Re-installing DirectX.
4. Upgrading/Downgrading graphics and audio drivers.
5. going back to an old system restore point.
6. Re-installing Visual Studio

Comment: Did you upgrade your OS recently?

Comment: No I did nothing between multiple consecutive runs it just suddenly started happening although I never touch any of the rendering pipeline code

Comment: I'd first make sure to do a full clean rebuild as it could be a corruption issue.

Comment: Yes I have already done tat multiple times but that doesn't help either